# Problem in sizeof() operator and poiner declaration

Tags: c, pointers, sizeof

This question was asked in my Sem-2 examination. Question asked us to give the desired output.

```
int main(void)
{
    int a[] = {10,20,30,40,50,60};

    int (*p1)[2]=a , (*p2)[3]= a;

    if(sizeof(p1)==sizeof(p2))
    printf("%d",*(*p1+2));

    if(sizeof(*p1)==sizeof(*p2))
    printf("%d",*(*(p2+1)));

    return(0);
}
```

Compiler warnings:

```
Warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
         initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
```

Output that I expect: 20

Output that I get when I run it: 30

Using : gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0

Comment: "desired output" should probably just say "output". **My desired output is that the compiler, instead of outputting warnings, would output errors, and stop this broken code from compiling.**

Comment: What do you want to do here  : **int (*p1)[2]=a , (*p2)[3]= a;**  ?!

Comment: Thanks for guiding  , I will try to correct my syntax in future post . Mr . Anitti can you please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ignore the undefined behavior to work out what is probably happening.

`p1` and `p2` are both pointing to `a[0]` (ignoring the incompatible pointer types).

`p1` and `p2` are both pointers. Pointers to object types are generally the same size (assume this is the case), so `sizeof(p1)==sizeof(p2)` will be true.

`p1` is of type `int (*)[2]`, so `*p1` is of type `int[2]`. In most expressions, an array will decay to a pointer to its first element, so in the expression `*(*p1+2)`, `*p1` will decay to an `int *` and will be pointing to `a[0]`. Therefore `*p1+2` will be pointing to `a[2]`. Therefore `*(*p1+2)` will be the same as `a[2]`, which has the value `30`. Therefore the program prints `30`.

An array does not decay to a pointer when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator. `*p1` is of type `int[2]` and `*p2` is of type `int[3]`, so `sizeof(*p1)==sizeof(*p2)` is equivalent to `sizeof(int[2])==sizeof(int[3])`, which is false. Therefore the second `printf` call that prints the value of `*(*p2+1)` is not evaluated.

(Let's pretend the second `printf` is called and that `*(*p2+1)` is evaluated. `*p2` is of type `int[3]` and in this expression it decays to an `int *` pointing to `a[0]`. Therefore `*p2+1` points to `a[1]`. Therefore, `*(*p2+1)` will be the same as `a[1],` which has the value `20`.)

Comment: Thank you, it was interesting for me, too.