# Using Pointer to Display/Change previously created array not working after user inputs

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main()
{
    int r, c, i=0, size_e, size_j;// First list of ints to be used in the program
    printf("Input numbers of elements in the array: ");//Initializing user to ask for elements to the array
    while(scanf("%d", &size_e) != 1)
    {
        printf("Invalid entry, please input a valid entry: \n");
        while(getchar() != '\n' ){}
    }
    printf("How many columns do you have: ");//Number of columns
    while(scanf("%d", &size_j) !=1 )
    {
        printf("Invalid entry, please input a valid entry: \n");
        while(getchar() != '\n' ){}
    }
    while ((size_e % size_j) != 0)
    {
        printf("Number of elements must be divisible by the number of columns. Try again! \n ");
        while(getchar() != '\n' ){}
        exit (0);
    }

    int array[size_e];

    printf("The error is after this: ");

    for (r = 0; r < size_e ; r++)
    {
        printf("Input the value for %d: ", r + 1);
        while(scanf("%d", &array [r]) != 1)
        {
            printf("Please input a correct value: ");
            while(getchar() != '\n' ){}
        }
    }
    printf("The error is after this: ");

    int **matrix[size_e / size_j][size_j];
    for (r = 0; r < (size_e / size_j) ; r++)
    {
        for (c = 0; c < size_j; c++)
        {
            **matrix[r][c] = array[i];
            ++i;
        }
    }
    printf("This is your matrix: \n");
    printf("The error is after this: ");

    for (r=0; r< (size_e / size_j) ; r++)
    {

        for (c = 0; c < size_j; c++)
        {
            printf("%d ", **matrix[r][c]);
            if (c == size_j - 1)
                printf("\n");
        }
    }
    int row, col, val;
    printf("Type in what value you wish to change indicated <row> <column> <value>\n or enter any letter to quit to quit \n ");
    while((scanf("%d %d %d", &row, &col, &val ) == 3))
    {
        **matrix[row][col] = val;
        printf("Type in what value you wish to change indicated <row> <column> <value>\n or enter any letter to quit \n ");
        while(getchar() != '\n' ){}
        for (r=0; r< (size_e / size_j) ; r++)
        {

            for (c = 0; c < size_j; c++)
            {
                printf("%d ", **matrix[r][c]);
                if (c == size_j - 1)
                    printf("\n");
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
```

I am a greenhorn to coding and I've been tripped up on this for quite some time. My code was working previously deferencing the address through *(*(blah + blah) + blah) but I'm required to use an array of pointers to convert the 1d user defined array to the 2d user defined "matrix". Only issue is after the user puts in their inputs, it kicks me out following `int array[size_e];
printf("The error is after this: ");`
All the operations after don't work but the compiler doesn't give me any flags

Comment: I've seen a similar question few days ago. ```int **matrix[size_e / size_j][size_j];``` You declare an array of pointers to pointers to ints, allocate memory for it etc. And as far as I can see, you want to declare a single pointer to a variable of type "a 2D array with following dimensions". I'll try to find the example.

Comment: Found it! This is an example of a pointer to an existing array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285607/problem-in-sizeof-operator-and-poiner-declaration

Comment: @NickDoom I appreciate it thank you so much! Was able to look back and reflect on the idea for the lab we did today which required something similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`matrix` is a 2-dimensional array of pointers to pointers. But you never initialized any of the pointers.

If you want the elements of `matrix` to refer to the corresponding elements of `array`, they should just be pointers, not pointers to pointers. And then you need to set them to the addresses of the array elements.

```
int *matrix[size_e / size_j][size_j];
for (r = 0; r < (size_e / size_j) ; r++)
{
    for (c = 0; c < size_j; c++)
    {
        matrix[r][c] = &array[i];
        ++i;
    }
}
```

After this, accessing `*matrix[r][c]` is equivalent to accessing `array[r * size_j + c]`.

Comment: OOOH that makes more sense, I thought I had an issue when declaring the pointers but I wasn't entirely sure. I think my issue was that I was heavily thinking about the de referencing notation and that messed me up. Thanks a lot for the clarification!